# How to handle unordered bucket boundaries in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need to retrieve all profile views a user received within 15 days. I made a working query that group all views by day.

A view is a very simple document:

```js
{
viewerId: string,
username: string,
profileId: string,
day: 4
}
```

The `day` key matches the current day of the month when the view was stored. So I made this query:

```js
static getProfileViews(userId: string) {
    const fifteenDaysRange = this.getDaysRange(15);
    return ProfileViewsDB.aggregate([
      { $match: { profileId: userId } },
      {
        $bucket: {
          groupBy: "$day",
          boundaries: fifteenDaysRange,
          default: fifteenDaysRange[fifteenDaysRange.length - 1] + 1,
          output: {
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
            viewers: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$viewerId",
                username: "$username",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
  }
```

It works, except when the days range is across two months. So the boundaries are: `[29 ,30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, instead of a regular incremental list. In this case, mongo crashes, claiming that the boundaries must be properly ordered.

How to fix this? Is there a trick here to handle this edge-case?

Comment: Why do you use `$bucket`? Simple `$match` and `$group` should do the job.

Comment: A `$group` should indeed do the job, but if you insist on using `$bucket`, then you have to make the boundaries always ascending. By using full date strings, for example ("2021-04-12"). This will handle crossing month and year boundaries.

Comment: How would you do it with group?

Comment: Simply `{$group: {_id: "$day", count: {$sum: 1}, ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you are looking for, but I assume it should work with this:

```
db.ProfileViewsDB.aggregate([
   { $match: { profileId: userId } },
   { $match: { date: { $gte: moment().startOf('day').subtract(15, 'day').toDate() } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { y: { $year: "$date" }, m: { $month: "$date" }, d: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" } },
         count: { $sum: 1 },
         viewers: {
            $push: { _id: "$viewerId", username: "$username", },
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Whenever one has to work with date/times then I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library, it makes your life easier.

Note, you may add the timezone, i.e.

```
_id: { 
   y: { $year: "$date", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" }, 
   m: { $month: "$date", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" }, 
   d: { $dayOfMonth: "$date", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" } 
}
```